# EF Core Left Outer Join failing with nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am currently struggling with a EntityFramework Core query.
Basically I am applying a LEFT OUTER JOIN (besides of other INNER JOINS).

The first table is `Solutions` and is basically the foundation, a separate table 'SolutionViews' tracks each single `view` of a `Solution`, so let's say the solution with Id 1 has 2 views, you will find 2 rows in `SolutionViews` that point to the SolutionId. At the end I aggregate all the rows based on the SolutionId to get the total views per solution.

Here's the SQL Query that I am basically trying to replicate:

```
SELECT solution.Id, solution.Name, category.Name, Count(solutionView.SolutionId) As 'Views'
FROM Solutions solution
JOIN Categories category on solution.CategoryId = category.Id
LEFT JOIN SolutionViews solutionView on solution.Id = solutionView.SolutionId
GROUP BY solution.Id, solution.Name, category.Name
ORDER BY Views desc
```

The result of that query looks like this:

```
Id  Name        CategoryId  Name        Views
9   Solution4   3           Category1   3
1   Solution1   1           Category2   2
2   Solution2   2           Category1   1
8   Solution3   3           Category3   0
10  Solution5   3           Category3   0
```

Using EF Core 2.1 I've tried at first the I think so called 'fluent' syntax (as I liked the concept) with just using LINQ, but switchedo ver to the query syntax below:

```
    var query = (from solution in context.Solutions
                 join category in context.Categories
                 on solution.CategoryId equals category.Id
                 join view in context.SolutionViews.GroupBy(sv => sv.SolutionId)
                     .Select(g => new {
                         SolutionId = g.Key,
                         Views = g.Count()
                     })
                 on solution.Id equals view.SolutionId into a
                 from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new SolutionWithViewsDto {
                     Solution = solution,
                     Views = b == null ? 0 : b.Views
                 }
        );
```

I left out the OrderBy as I am dynamically adding that later based on the API search specifications, but right now this query is providing me with an exception:
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'**

I'm pretty sure this originates from the fact that some records do not have any entries in the SolutionViews table, and hence I am doing the LEFT OUTER JOIN wrong.

Comment: Why not use the Navigation properties instead of doing joins?

Comment: I tried that at first (and would love that) but ended up with not being able to utilize OrderBy on the calculated Views column, let me see if I have that query still to add it to the question

Comment: Also your SQL is missing a `Group By` which is required to do that `Count`.

Comment: The GroupBy is happening before the .Select()

Comment: But maybe this is where I already have a mistake in my thinking

Comment: I mean the actual SQL code not the Linq code.

Comment: Oh, that's a copy & paste mistake, let me fix that!

Comment: Copied the correct query, my bad! Somehow lost the 2 lines when I created the post

Comment: Sounds like client evaluation bug. Not yours, but still you'd better use navigation properties and no `GroupBy` - the LINQ query should be simple `Select`, e.g. something like  `context.Solutions.Select(s => new { s.Id, s.Name, CatgoryName = s.Category.Name, Views = s.Views.Count() })`. Also avoid mixing entities with DTOs - create DTO with just primitive fields you need and select into it.

Comment: Hm, I feel like I did encounter a few bugs but then also I am not an expert on EF Core, I was utilizing the .GroupJoin() with the Navigation Properties to get that Count. I have other joins that I was able to make work (many to many, 1 to 1) but somehow I am struggling with this Count. I will post the Navigation property version shortly

Comment: @IvanStoev wow, I never realized I can just use .Count() within the .Select() statement that easily without specifying anything further, I guess I was too much in the SQL mindset. Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it? Definitely was a lack of understanding on my end on EF Core and how much Navigation Properties already take care of resolving everything! Although I would have expected that the query syntax should work too... thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits go to Ivan Stoev, I am just providing a visible answer to this. The query syntax seems to be behaving a bit buggy, but in the end what did work was using only `Navigation Properties`, which is much easier too. All I had to do was apply `.Count()` on the `SolutionsView` navigation property, which will give you the count of views for each individual `Solution` record.

```
var query = context.Solutions
                .Select(s => new SolutionDto {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    Description = s.Description,
                    Category = new CategoryDto {
                        Id = s.Category.Id,
                        Name = s.Category.Name
                    },
                    Views = s.SolutionViews.Count()
                });
```